# Find the rank of the following matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & 2 \\
-6 & 2 & 4 \\
-3 & 1 & 2 \end{array} \right]$

Applying, $R_{3}-\frac{1}{2}R_{2}$

~ $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & 2 \\
-6 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$

Applying, $R_{2}+2R_{1}$

~ $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$

Comment: Rows 2 and 3 are scalars. Rank 2.

Answer (score 3):

Row reduce the matrix and count the nonzero rows that remain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a row of zeros, the rank is at most $2$: two non-zero rows. If the matrix can be reduced further, you may have another row of zeros, in which case one non-zero row remains: rank 1.

ADDED: Given your work/edit, how many NON-ZERO rows remain? That gives you the **rank** of the original matrix.

---

For a "refresher", see this link, with various *equivalent* definitions of the [rank of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Main_definitions).

Comment: Always nice advice! +1